# CASE-WHEN-THEN-ELSE construct in SQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm looking for some help with a SQL query with an IF-THEN-ELSE construction.
It revolves around the automatism in my application after an insert of a new row in a "dump"-table -depending on the value of one column - to copy to a special table.

In order to exercise it, I made a test DB with a table prob and a table prob2

The trigger mechanism is under control.
Now it still comes to what to do with that special rule. This depends on the value of "c"

In words this is what I want:

```
IF ( the value in column c of the prob-table - from the row with the highest ID of the prob table = 2 )
THEN (Now, copy this line to the prob2 table)
END IF
```

This way I can for each value of "c" perform a different action in a IF-THEN - ELSEIF - THEN - ELSEIF - THEN - END IF construction.

Table prob:

```
 - id   |      a        | b | c |
 -  ----+---------------+---+---+ 
 - 1    |std745_900w    | 5 | 4 |
 -  ----+---------------+---+---+ 
 - 2    |std745_900w    | 2 | 3 |
 -  ----+---------------+---+---+ 
 - 3    |std745_900w    | 1 | 9 |
 -  ----+---------------+---+---+ 
 - 4    |std745_900w    | 3 | 2 |
 -  ----+---------------+---+---+
```

My translation into a (NOT WORKING) SQL Query

```
IF
  (SELECT c  FROM prob WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM prob ) = 2 )
THEN
  (INSERT INTO prob2 ( id, a, b, c )
   SELECT id, a, b, c FROM prob WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM prob) )
END IF
```

The query after the IF between brackets) -->   `SELECT c  FROM prob WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM prob)` <--  is working oke and results in "2"
The query after the THEN  --> `INSERT INTO prob2 ( id, a, b, c ) SELECT id, a, b, c FROM prob WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM prob)`  <-- works well
SQL, however, does not understand the expression of the "IF Statement".

This is mysql on a MariaDB

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you saying you have an insert trigger on table prob and you want to include this logic in that trigger?

Comment: In MySQL an if ... then - else ... end if statement can only be used in stored programs (procedure, function, trigger), you can't run it as is. Retrieving data from the database is also slightly different.

Comment: Yes, In MariaDB you can define a trigger after an insert on a table. This triggers a SQL query. I tested it with a simple query and that works. My trouble lies in the test in the IF part of the it-then- else construct

Comment: In an after insert trigger the new prefix holds the value inserted to a field. So (for example) new,c might be what you want to use in your if tests.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
CASE WHEN (your_test) THEN (do_something_here) ELSE
```

you can use many 'when ... then'

Answer (score 0):

Missing some details, but you can do this in MySQL procedural language and call it from the trigger:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE COPY_ROW () 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE pId INT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE pC INT DEFAULT 0;

        SELECT id, c
        INTO pId, pC
        FROM prob 
        WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM prob );

        IF(pC = 2) THEN
             INSERT INTO prob2 ( id, a, b, c )
             SELECT id, a, b, c FROM prob WHERE id = pId;

        END IF;
     END;
```

Comment: Yes, it's the procedural language for MySql

Comment: Er no plsql is the procedural language for Oracle

Comment: Well, I edited my response. This is code for the procedural language in MySql. It is not called PLSQL as you argue, but I used it as acronym. sorry

Comment: Thanks!! Working with procedures is the answer! This is the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT @c := c FROM prob ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
IF @c = 2 THEN
    INSERT INTO prob2 (id, a, b, c)
         SELECT id, a, b, c FROM prob ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
END IF
```

You had troubles with parentheses.  And subqueries to get `MAX(id)` are often better done via `ORDER BY`.

Comment: I suppose these construction works only in a procedure? MariaDB provides a syntax error @c

Comment: True.  `IF`, as a statement, works only in Stored Routines.  Would you explain what you are trying to do?  There may be an even simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the ints and tips. Working with a procedure is the answer to this problem.
Thanks to you all!